# Getting error 'No authorization header passed' with PHP's POST CURL request - envato api

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0

I'm getting started with the [Enavato API](https://build.envato.com/api#market_ItemPrices)

So far I've created an app, got `client_id` & `client_secret` and managed to get the `code` access_key from the `https://api.envato.com/authorization` after that I'm using the below php code to make POST curl request

```php
$client_id      = '***********';
$client_secret  = '***********';
$redirect_uri   = urlencode('http://localhost:3000');

if(isset($_GET["code"])) :  

  $apiUrl = 'https://api.envato.com/token';
  $params = array(
    'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
    'code'          => $_GET["code"],
    'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
    'client_id'     => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
  );

  $curl = curl_init();
  $f = fopen('request.txt', 'w');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);

  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  fclose($f);

  // Check if any error occurred
  if(empty($result))
  { 
    // die(curl_errno($curl));
    // die(curl_error($curl));
     $info = curl_getinfo($curl);

     echo '<br><br>';
     echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
     echo '<br><br>';
     var_dump($info);
     echo '<br><br>';
  }

  var_dump($result);

  // Close handle
  curl_close($curl);

endif;
```

and here is the `request.txt` dump

```
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 107.23.230.180...
* Connected to api.envato.com (107.23.230.180) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.envato.com
* Server certificate: RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
> POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.envato.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 699
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------1a95a06d7b815306

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Sun, 17 May 2015 17:03:41 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
* Server nginx/1.7.10 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.7.10
< set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3ARC9gGye-Txp4KLp67M9ESspXijYoUc8i.pT3jYHvu1WyOsSjwsuQzEsy5hLQlc2QpmHkZRm05pXo; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Frame-Options: Deny
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Length: 80
< Connection: keep-alive
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

and finally the error(getting it in JSON)

> string(80) "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"No authorization header passed"}"

Astonishingly every thing is working with [Postman](http://getpostman.com) and I'm getting "refresh_token" and "access_token" with a success 200 status code.

I know I'm missing some thing but couldn't find what?

Comment: can you provide access keys or do we have to create an app to answer this question? lol!!

Comment: I wish I could, but that is against envato's terms. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);` with `$params` being an array. That results in a HTTP POST message with `multipart/form-data` content type and formatting. But the spec says the content type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You can achieve this by using:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
```

You also don't need to `urlencode` the `redirect_uri` parameter, since `http_build_query` will do it for you.

Lastly, do not turn off SSL validation (`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`) since it renders your system insecure.

Comment: I was unable to find any bugs or warnings, so I tried to remove every possible bug(thought of SSL issue or  url encode issue) odd man out, but missed the spec details. Hey that was really helpful.  ;)

Comment: How or where did you found that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I'm unable to find it in docs?